# Understanding Express documentation for middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

I am a beginner and struggle to read documentation although, practically, I can understand what the documentation says by looking at the code implementation.

For example, `app.use([path,] callback [, callback...])`

I understand how to use the method but I still have no clear understanding of the notation used in the documentation. For instance, questions that I have in mind:

1. Why is the path inside a square bracket?
2. What does the comma mean after it? Does it mean that I can add more than one path?
3. After the callback, we have a square bracket containing the comma and callback and triple dots, what does it mean?

I hope somebody can help me, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Providing a link to the relevant documentation helps increase the relevance of the post.

Answer (score 1):

For general context, `use` adds a [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) function(s) to the Express request handler.

1. The `path` parameter is in a square bracket because it's optional. If you omit it, then the middleware callback is applied to all incoming requests. If you provide a path string, then only requests matching the path will be passed to the middleware callback.
2. No, it just means that when you do use `path`, there is a comma delimiting it from the required `callback` second parameter. Because the second parameter `callback` isn't in brackets, it's required. The parameter list would look weird if this comma wasn't there after `path`, because it wouldn't match the JS syntax you'd use to provide multiple parameters to a function.
3. The triple dots in `callback...` means you can provide multiple callbacks.